# HTML Drag and Drop em celular (telas touchscreen)

Tags: html

Estou pensando em fazer um painel usando os recursos de **Drag and Drop** do HTML.

Exemplo retirado de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_draganddrop.asp)

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <p>Arraste para o retângulo:</p>

  <div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <img id="drag1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwI5h.png?s=48&g=1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">

</body>
</html>
```

---

Gostaria de saber, como faço para deixar funcional esse recurso quando for **aberto em um celular** (ou outra tela touchscreen), pois o "clique" é diferente:

- Se eu tocar e soltar, seria um clique
- Se eu tocar e segurar, abre as opções

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu já tive esse problema e acabei usando essa solução: http://bernardo-castilho.github.io/DragDropTouch/

O script do Bernardo Castilho sobrescreve os eventos e faz eles ficarem compatíveis com o touch, pode resolver o seu problema.

`jQuery` também tem uma solução, mas como você postou o código em puro javascript, acho que essa solução esteja mais de acordo com o que procura.

Aqui o arquivo js: [DragDropTouch.js](http://bernardo-castilho.github.io/DragDropTouch/DragDropTouch.js)

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo o uso do Sortable:

- [Rubaxa/Sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) Esse cara é um plugin que usa recursos nativos para drag and drop responsivo, ele pode ser implementado com qualquer framework CSS